# Yom tov and non-Jews

Tags: gentiles, yom-tov, vayera

How was Avraham Avinu able to cook for the melachim if he thought they were Arabs and you’re not allowed to cook for non-Jews on yom tov?

Comment: Why do you think it was yom tov?

Comment: Rashi says it was

Comment: @Josh are you maybe confusing with Lot? (Bereshit 19:3)

Comment: Rashi does not say this in this verses @Josh. Please add-in any information you have.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.11a.13

Comment: Rashi on the passuk כעת חיה ולשרה בן  brings a Medrash and the sifsei chachamim in that passuk says that yitzchak was born on Pesach

Comment: And if the melachim said exactly a year later yitzchak will be born means a year before was Pesach

Comment: @Josh it is broadly agreed that the angels visiting Avaraham and Lot occurred during Pesach. as I'm sure you are aware, however, Pesach includes both Yomim Tovim and Chol HaMoed. What makes you think the visit occurred on the former rather than the latter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Mizrachi on that Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Mizrachi%2C_Genesis.18.1.2?lang=bi) says it was on the 17th of Nissan:

> א"נ מה שפי' גבי כעת חיה פסח היה הוא בעד י"ז בניסן שהוא בפסח ומה שאמר ובפסח הבא נולד יצחק הוא בט"ו

The [Maharal](https://www.sefaria.org/Gur_Aryeh_on_Bereishit.18.10.1?lang=bi) says that as well

> והא דפסח היה יליף ליה לקמן דכתיב (יט, ג) "ומצות אפה" גבי לוט (רש"י שם), ולא שהיה יום ראשון של פסח, רק יום ג' של פסח, ומפני שאין לאכול חמץ – אפה מצה. וכן בב"ר (מח, יב) אמרו – "לושי ועשי עגות" (פסוק ו) – 'פרוס הפסח היה', והיינו יום ג' של פסח.

The [Maharsha in Rosh Hashana](https://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Agadot_on_Rosh_Hashanah.11a.10?lang=bi) says this as well:

> ותלמוד דהכא נמי ס"ל דלמועד הזה בשנה האחרת וגו' דבניסן היה דהכי נמי משמע בשנה האחרת למועד הזה ואז סרט לו סריטה וכיון דבט"ו בניסן נולד יצחק ע"כ מאמר דלמועד הזה בשנה וגו' נמי בט"ו בניסן הוה ובו ביום נימול אברהם וביאת המלאכים ביום ג' למילתו היה בי"ז בניסן כדברי רבי חמא

Once it is established that it was on the 17th which is chol hamoed, the question of cooking for a non Jew is not an issue.

Comment: I understand,I was really coming from a chasam sofer who asks this question brought down in aruch chaim teshuva 79

Comment: And he says in derashos he elaborates more but couldn’t find it in derashos